# iphone SDK: How to implement a signature capture?

Tags: iphone

How can I capture a users signature? The idea is that the user will use their fingers to draw their signature in a box. Part of the saving process will be to write this image to their Photos folder.

Comment: I am researching the same problem - so far this seems like the best solution I have found: http://www.tenonedesign.com/t1autograph.php

Answer (score 5):

I think this will do it.

http://www.ipodtouchfans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=132024

After that, I think the ability to save a screen capture will do the job.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size); //self.view.window.frame.size
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: what should we write in renderInContext: Method please clear me about this method