# How can I store signature/ autograph as image on iPad?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to store autograph on iPad as image. I am not getting any clue to do so. I have tried to find resource but I can't get anything. Let me know if this is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out this question, might point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630576/iphone-sdk-how-to-implement-a-signature-capture

Comment: Are you looking for how to capture a signature, or how to store the signature as an image, or both?

Comment: I am researching the same problem - so far this seems like the best solution I have found: http://www.tenonedesign.com/t1autograph.php