# How to sign using a mouse in Iphone

Tags: iphone, signature

I have to make an application where i need digital signature for authentication before a transaction completes.

Now i do not know how to implement the same. My requirements are:-

1. A screen where i can sign by swyping my fingers .

Now can anyone please tell me how to do make such a screen where i can sign using my fingers and it can be captured at the back.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone SDK: How to implement a signature capture?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630576/iphone-sdk-how-to-implement-a-signature-capture)

Comment: Perhaps you could let a person take a picture of their signature, and send you the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{

    mouseSwiped = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        drawImage.image = nil;
        return;
    }

    if ((lastPoint.x<17 && lastPoint.y < 116) || (lastPoint.x>287 && lastPoint.y >159))
        NSLog(@"Outside");
    else
    {
        lastPoint = [touch locationInView:vw];
        //          lastPoint.y -= 20;
    }

}


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    mouseSwiped = YES;

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:vw];

    if ((currentPoint.x<17 && currentPoint.y < 116) || (currentPoint.x>287 && currentPoint.y >159))
        NSLog(@"Outside");
    else
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(vw.frame.size);
        [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, vw.frame.size.width, vw.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        lastPoint = currentPoint;

        mouseMoved++;

        if (mouseMoved == 10) {
            mouseMoved = 0;
        }
    }

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{   
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:vw];


    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        drawImage.image = nil;
        return;
    }

    if ((currentPoint.x<20 && currentPoint.y < 199) || (currentPoint.x>743 && currentPoint.y >425))
        NSLog(@"Outside");
    else
    {
        if(!mouseSwiped) 
        {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(vw.frame.size);
            [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, vw.frame.size.width, vw.frame.size.height)];
            CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
            CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
            CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
            CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
            drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add this in viewdidload := drawImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
 drawImage.frame = vw.frame;
 [self.view addSubview:drawImage];
 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
 mouseMoved = 0;
 imgViewSignYes.hidden = TRUE;

Comment: @7kv7: i will take care of it next time. Thanks.

Comment: Very nice code. but in when we start swipe on screen it starts from the upper left corner. +1 from my side.thx

Comment: @mitesh: thnx. Glad it helped you. :)

Comment: hey i hav added touchesBegan and touchesMoved function in my code..Can anybody tell what changes are required to be made in xib file? To make it drawable through mouse as when it runs it just display a blank view

Comment: @sudhanshu: add a view on which you want to take signature in .xib then write this code in .h file  //Signature Variables
 UIImageView *drawImage;
 CGPoint lastPoint;
 BOOL mouseSwiped; 
 int mouseMoved;
 IBOutlet UIView *vw;